# Basic CSS positioning issue

Tags: html, css

I have 3 boxes. When setting the middle's position to relative (to 'body' in this case) and negative top, the box below doesn't move up too. How could I do that?

HTML:

```
<div class="box" id="up"></div>
<div class="box" id="middle"></div>
<div class="box" id="down"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.box {
  width: 400px;
  height:200px;
  position: relative;
}

#up {
  background: red;
}

#middle {
  top: -50px;
  background: green;
}

#down {
  background: blue;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dBgbz/

**EDIT:** I forgot to say that I've tried with negative margin-top, but works except for Internet Explorer. Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Basically, you want the blue box to follow the green box's position?

Comment: Yes. I've tried with margin-top I forgot to say, and works except for Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 2):

**Define your** `#middle` `margin-top: -50px` and **remove** `top : -50px`

```
#middle {
margin-top:-50px;  // add this  
top: -50px;  // remove this 
  background: green;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohitmalikazad/Z8J2C/1/)**

Comment: I forgot to say that I've tried that, but the problem is that way it doesn't work on IE...

Answer (score 0):

Do you add the top yet to #down box:

```
#down {
  top: -50px;
  background: blue;
}
```